# Taylor theorem remainder term

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm having trouble applying the formula for the remainder in the Taylor's theorem.

From Wikipedia we know that for

$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+…\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^{n}+R$

the remainder $R$ in the integral form is

$R=\int_{a}^{x}\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^{k}dt$

Now, what I want to do is, for the following expansions

1) $\psi_{0}(\lambda_{0}x+(\lambda-\lambda_{0})x)=\psi_{0}(\lambda_{0}x)+\psi_{0}'(z)(\lambda-\lambda_{0})x$

2) $\phi(\psi_{0}(\lambda_{0}x)+\psi_{0}'(z)(\lambda-\lambda_{0})x)=\phi(\psi_{0}(\lambda_{0}x))+\phi'(\alpha)\psi_{0}'(z)(\lambda-\lambda_{0})x$

with $z=z(x,\lambda,\lambda_{0})$, $\alpha=\alpha(x,\lambda,\lambda_{0})$, to write down the first derivative terms on the right hand side as the remainder terms of appropriate order.

I am not sure if I "translated" the Wikipedia formula correctly for my expansions, but here is what I got:

1) $\psi_{0}'(z)(\lambda-\lambda_{0})x=\int_{\lambda_{0}x}^{\lambda_{0}x+(\lambda-\lambda_{0})x}\psi_{0}'(t)dt=\int_{\lambda_{0}}^{\lambda}x\psi_{0}'(sx)ds$ (in the last step I used a change of variables $t\mapsto sx$)

2) $\phi'(\alpha)\psi_{0}'(z)(\lambda-\lambda_{0})x=\int_{\psi_{0}(\lambda_{0}x)}^{\psi_{0}(\lambda_{0}x)+\psi_{0}'(z)(\lambda-\lambda_{0})x}\phi'(t)dt$

Can anyone please tell me if my calculations are correct/where did I make a mistake?
Also, in the integral for 2), which change of variables can I use to get the integral go from $\lambda_{0}$ to $\lambda$?

Many thanks! (this is not homework)

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: I did not understand what are you trying to do(prove)?

Comment: @boywholived I simply need someone to check that a) my integral expressions are correct, and b) if they are, I have a change of variables questions that I wrote

Comment: $\psi_{0}'(z)(\lambda-\lambda_{0})x=\int_{{\lambda}_{0}x}^{\lambda_{0}x+(\lambda-\lambda_{0})x}\psi_{0}'(t)dt=\int_{\lambda_{0}}^{\lambda}x\psi_{0}'(sx)ds$ That expression is not correct. How did you get the first equality?.

Comment: @boywholived ok could you maybe write an answer and explain what's wrong with it? I gave my best solution, meaning that if I knew what's wrong with it I would have already corrected it. Thanks!

Comment: Mathematics is based on reasoning. So only if you can tell how $ \psi_{0}'(z)(\lambda-\lambda_{0})x=\int_{{\lambda}_{0}x}^{\lambda_{0}x+(\lambda‌​-\lambda_{0})x}\psi_{0}'(t)dt$ this is true, then only we can accept that it is true. Basically $f^{'}{z}=\int{f^{'}{x}dx}$? correct?(Even $f^{'}$ is integrable for granted), that is not true for all $f(x)$.

Comment: ok here is my reasoning: the wikipedia definition gives the integral from $a$ to $x$. In my case 1), $a$ corresponded to $\lambda_{0}x$ and $x$ corresponded to $\lambda x$. I read it off from my expansion formula 1). @boywholived